# using Assembly(language) in a UWP App?

Tags: assembly, uwp, universal

I was wondering if it is possible to "use" assembly language inside a C++ project that will go target UWP?

I was going to rewrite an old Atari game from DASM to MASM, but I want the end product to run in an UWP.

I have successfully ran MASM code in a C++ console app, but before I get too ahead of myself I wanted to check with the community if this is possible in an UWP.

Thoughts?

Comment: The scary quotes around "use" are useless.  You cannot write assembly code in a C# project and you cannot start another process like an assembler.

Comment: Last time I've checked, Atari computers used a Motorola 680x0 CPU. Its assembly is completely unlike either Intel or ARM assembly that UWP supports. It will be not a porting effort, but a complete rewrite from scratch. Are you sure you're up for the task?

Comment: I anticipate a complete rewrite, with the existing source as a guide.  Perhaps VC++ is the better route not C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ Universal Windows Platforms apps compile to native code, so there's no reason why you shouldn't be able be able to include assembly language files in your C++ UWP project. You should also be able to use assembly language in a C# project indirectly using .NET's P/Invoke and COM interoperability facilities, you like you can with C++ code. In theory at least you could also translate the assembly code to [Common Intermediate Language (CIL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) and use that directly in a C# project.

That said I don't know if it makes sense translate an old Atari game written in assembly for a different CPU architecture into x86 assembly. It would be easier to translate it to C# or C++, whichever language you're familiar with. Performance shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I have a VC++ UWP app that successfully adds some numbers together and returns from the assembly object. Hooray!